# Laravel Export data to Excel sheet error

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, export

What i need is export data table details into excel file.so that here is the controller which i developed.

```
    public function export(){
    $items = registerdetails::all();
    Excel::create('Export Data', function($excel) use($item){
    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($item){

        $sheet->fromArray($item);

    });

})->export('xlsx');
}
```

Relevant route for that is.

`Route::get('ExportData', 'UserRegisterController@export');`

i don't create view for this but i called this route via a button called Download All Trainees in index page.

`<a class="btn btn-success " href="{{URL::to('ExportData')}}">Dowanload All Trainees</a>`

Finally here is the error i`m getting now.

[image]

Can anyone help me solve this please.

Comment: You assign `$items`, but use `$item`

Comment: Yeah i fixed it sir,thank u ,make this as a answer then i ll mark ur answer